# How do I add an index for the updatedAt system field?

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I know you can add an Index attribute to a field of an EntityData subclass, which creates an SQL Server index.   I would like to know how to do the same for system fields like updatedAt.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know how to do the same for system fields like updatedAt.

I suggest you could set index for **updatedAt** field  in portal directly.  And from this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.mobileservicesystemcolumns.updatedat?view=azure-dotnet), you could see the updatedAt field is readonly. So you can not change it.
[image]

Comment: I'm trying to avoid manually creating indices as every time I recreate the database I have to remember to add them in.

Comment: Did you mean you want to set the index of updatedAt filed to be true by default? But these fields are all created by system.You can not change the internal rules.

Comment: Yes, that is the essence of the question.   I know you can hide a property in a subclass and apply an index attribute to it, but I don't know if there are any side effects that I should consider.

Comment: @jp2g I have updated my answer. I hope my answer could be helpful. The system fields are created by system, if you insist on changing them, it's not a good way. This will change the system rules. The id and createdAt fields already have indexes, it seems that no need more. Many indexes would affect performance and storage overhead.

Comment: The article is for the client api.   My question concerns the server-side sql server.   As you may know, the updatedAt property is used in the paging mechanism when a PullAsync is done on the (UWP) client.   Therefore, it is in every WHERE clause.   My tests show there is a noticeable sync performance improvement by indexing on this field.

Comment: It seems to be impossible to achieve in mobile service. You say you want to add index to updatedAt field by default every time you recreate the database. But before you create the database, there is nothing..   Only if you have already created the database, you could see these fields and operate them. That's conflict. In mobile service UI, there is only "Add+" button, you do not have access to the underlying code to change the rules for creating Azure tables.